# Swiper slider js with Pagination fraction

Tags: swiper.js, webflow

[image: example of my design]
I need help with swipe slider in webflow. It is necessary that the slides change on the left by clicking on the arrows at the bottom right, as well as the numbers of the slides between the arrows change and that the slider be infinite, that is, a loop. Help me please. I don't know how to code at all.

https://swiperjs.com/demos#pagination-fraction

I tried to use this one and absolutly don't understand how to make it.